How to find last application pool recycle time in IIS
Does IIS log the time when it (automatically) recycles the Application Pools?
Our is currently set to recycle every 1720 minutes (29 hours), but how do we tell when the next one will be?
I cannot find anything in the log.

Take a look at How to Find App Pool Recycles in Event Log.
